# Bazel: dynamic linking against DLL

Tags: c++, bazel, build-tools

This should be simple, but unfortunately it has given me hours of headache. I have a third party library with multiple DLL files. I want these to be included in the final bazel bin so that I can run my project.

Copying them manually works, but obviously this isn't ideal.

Bazel has docs which use CC_import rule, which seemed to be what I want, except that I need to use linkstatic=0

Using this it tries to build all my packages dynamically into shared object files. This isn't really what I want either , especially since it seems MinGw is failing to link against these.

I'm out of things I can try so any help would be infinitely appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Can this issue be connected to `.dll` extension stripping before passing to the linker? So the linker receives `-l<name>.dll` option instead of `-l<name>`?

By default MinGW GCC ld.exe doesn't look for `lib<name>.so` libraries for `-l<name>` option when run under Windows. It tries to find `lib<name>.dll`.

So in case `.dll` extension wasn't stripped off, ld receives `-l<name>.dll` option and looking for `lib<name>.dll.dll` which doesn't exist.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181059/21154355) I addressed this bug. This was fixed in 7.1.0 bazel release.

Comment: Hi Viktor! Much appreciate your answer. I'm glad you're giving mingw on windows some much needed love. In my case my issue is different unfortunately and a description can be found here https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/15848 , my interface library for the DLL isn't supported. Did you ever run into this issue?

Comment: @NightShade Hi! No, I didn't run into this yet. I also think this is an issue with bazel. May be a tiny change needed there, some case addition or regex correction as it was in my case. It must be somewhere deep inside java sources for cpp native rules perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I can save time for someone with this in future, since I finally worked out what my issue was. I think this is an issue with bazel, and so I have raised an issue on their [github page](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/15848).

I was trying to use the cc_import rule but hadn't specified a interface_library. This was having me run into all kinds of issues where it was trying to statically include the DLL. The interface_library is required.

My next issue was I coudln't specfiy a `.a` file for the interface library, which I believe GCC uses for linking against DLLs. This type isn't supported by bazel. I've raised an issue for this (as above).

My workaround currently is to manually copy the DLLs into the bazel-bin folder. Everything works perfectly if I use a supported file type for the interface_library.

Hope this saves someone time in the future :)

Comment: I don't think GCC typically uses import/Interface libraries. Normally it links directly with the *.so or *.dll. It does support import libs but unless you need to, why not link to the dynamic libs directly

Comment: In my case, I can't. I'm using a library called SFML and it provides import libraries to link against the DLLs. I don't seem to be able to link to them directly. If I don't provide any interface library, bazel seems to get upset, something about it can't find the DLL (and it seems to be trying to link against it with -l)