# Bazel. Building and linking .dll under Windows 11 using custom MinGW toolchain

Tags: windows, dll, bazel, ld, bazel-cpp

I'm trying to build dynamic library, then build executable, then link them together using Bazel. The toolchain is custom and uses MinGW ucrt64 GCC tools under Windows 11 Pro.

My `BUILD` file:

```
DLL_HDRS = ["math_import_defs.h", "math_dll_interface.h"]

load("//main:dll_library.bzl", "dll_library")

cc_binary(
    name = "sum_numbers_mingw",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"] + DLL_HDRS, 
    dynamic_deps = [":math_d_shared"]                   
)

dll_library(
    name = "math_d",
    srcs = ["math_dll_interface.cpp"],
    hdrs = DLL_HDRS,
    deps = [":math"],
    defines = ["MATH_DLL"]
)

cc_library(
    name = "math",
    srcs = ["math.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["math.h"],
    copts = ["-std=c++17"]
)
```

`.bzl` file with `dll_library` definition:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")
load("@rules_cc//examples:experimental_cc_shared_library.bzl", "cc_shared_library")

def dll_library(
        name,
        srcs = [],
        deps = [],
        hdrs = [],
        visibility = None,
        **kwargs):               
    static_library_name = name + "_static"
    dll_lib_name = name + "_shared"
    
    cc_library(
        name = static_library_name,
        srcs = srcs,
        hdrs = hdrs,
        deps = deps,        
        **kwargs
    )
    
    cc_shared_library(
        name = dll_lib_name,                        
        deps = [":" + static_library_name] 
    )
```

Everything goes fine until ld receives -lmath_d_shared option:

`C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmath_d_shared: No such file or directory`

This is because `cc_shared_library` generates `libmath_d_shared.so` library, but `ld` doesn't look for `.so` under Windows. Renaming library to `libmath_d_shared.dll` and running build again without deletion of previously generated targets solves the problem. `ld` finds `libmath_d_shared.dll` and everything works as expected.

Tried to tweak my toolchain by additional:

```
artifact_name_pattern(
    category_name = "dynamic_library",
    prefix = "lib",
    extension = ".dll",
)
```

in the `artifact_name_patterns` field.

It forces Bazel to add extension `.dll` to all generated dynamic libraries. But, for some reason, Bazel doesn't remove suffix `.dll` from library name while passing `-l` option to `ld`. So it passes `-lmath_d_shared.dll` option. Then `ld` can't find the library, because file `libmath_d_shared.dll.dll` doesn't exist.

Looking for workaround for this case. I need to, either fix the library name stripping process prior passing `-l` option to `ld`, or to implement renaming my library from `.so` to `.dll` automatically before linking with executable.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this fixed by creating [this pull request](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/21404). Merged into bazel release 7.1.0 [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/21524).